# C: Realloc issues with double pointer

Tags: c, realloc

I am trying to copy a `char word[50]` array to a `char **wordlist` double pointer and then `realloc(wordlist, (numwords+1)*sizeof(char*))` to increase the size of word list by one more `char*` to hold the next `word`.

I keep getting a `*** glibc detected *** ./program: realloc(): invalid next size` error

I am declaring it as `wordlist = realloc(wordlist, (numwords+1)*sizeof(char*))`

```
void outFile(char *argv[], char **wordlist)
  {
      if((inFilePtr = fopen(argv[2], "r")) != NULL)
      {
          if((outFilePtr = fopen(endOfFile, "w")) != NULL)
          {
              while((c = fgetc(inFilePtr)) != EOF)
              {
                  if(!(isspace(c)))
                  {
                      word[wordIndex] = c;
                      wordIndex++;
                      rowLim++;
                  }
                  if(isspace(c))
                  {
                      wordIndex = 0;
                      if(rowLim < limit)
                      {
                          rowLim++;
                          strcat(text[rowNum], word);
                          strcat(text[rowNum], " \0");
                          wordlist[numwords] = strdup(word);
                          /*strcat(wordlist[numwords], "\n\0");*/
                          memset(word, 0, 50);
                          prev = rowLim;
                          wordlist = realloc(wordlist, (numwords + 1)*sizeof(char*));
                          numwords++;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          strcat(text[rowNum], "\n\0");
                          printf("text[%d] = %s",rowNum, text[rowNum]);
                          fputs(text[rowNum], outFilePtr);
                          rowNum++;
                          strcat(text[rowNum], word);
                          strcat(text[rowNum], " \0");
                          /*strcat(wordlist[numwords], word);
                          strcat(wordlist[numwords], "\n\0");
                          wordlist = realloc(wordlist, (numwords + 1)*sizeof(char*));*/
                         numwords++;
                         memset(word, 0, 50);
                         rowLim = rowLim - prev;
                     }
                     wordIndex = 0;
                 }
             }
             strcat(text[rowNum], "\n\0");
             printf("text[%d] = %s",rowNum, text[rowNum]);
             fputs(text[rowNum], outFilePtr);
             fclose(outFilePtr);
         }
```

Comment: How so? Can you give more detail?

Comment: But numwords is initialized to 0, wouldn't that then always allocate space?

Comment: @PythonNoob post a MCVE. You made a mistake somewhere else in your program but it's impossible to say because you have not shown the rest of the program.

Comment: Problem number one (although it's in no way the reason of the problem), `wordlist = realloc(wordlist, (numwords+1)*sizeof(char*))` `realloc()` is not safely used the way you do. From the code you posted it's impossible to know why the `invalid next size...` message, please post a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PythonNoob from your comment *But numwords is initialized to 0, wouldn't that then always allocate space?*, it looks that we really really want to see the code ...

Comment: I made an edit. Does that help? I am trying to copy from one file, format it a bit, put each word in wordlist, and put the ouput in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the space before you have allocated it:

```
wordlist[numwords] = strdup(word);
wordlist = realloc(wordlist, (numwords + 1)*sizeof(char*));
numwords++;
```

Instead, allocate the space first:

```
wordlist = realloc(wordlist, (numwords + 1)*sizeof(char*));
wordlist[numwords] = strdup(word);
numwords++;
```

---

NB. As noted by iharob, if you wish to be able to recover from running out of memory, then the return value of `realloc` should be stored in a separate variable until you have confirmed that it is not `NULL`.

All of your `\0` are redundant. String literals are strings: for example `"\n"` means `{ '\n', '\0' }` already.

It's impossible to tell from this code whether you cause a buffer overflow by writing too much into `text[rowNum]`. I'd suggest redesigning this code to make sure that it can never overflow.

Comment: In my main method I have:
`char **wordlist = malloc(sizeof(shar*));`